# Email coming through as HTML garbage

Tags: email, html-email, zend-mail

I have been using Zend_Mail successfully for years, however recently some clients have reporting that emails come through "broken", when they forward it back, it looks like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


        X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18
        Message-Id: <20130107172629.F2A16E2011C@SERVER ADDRESS HERE>
        Date: Mon,  7 Jan 2013 17:26:29 +0000 (UTC)
        X-pstn-neptune: 0/0/0.00/0
        X-pstn-levels:     (S:75.53812/99.90000 CV:99.9000 FC:95.5390 LC:95.5390 R:95.9108 P:95.9108 M:97.0282 C:98.6951 )
        X-pstn-dkim: 0 skipped:not-enabled
        X-pstn-settings: 3 (1.0000:1.0000) s cv gt3 gt2 gt1 r p m c 
        X-pstn-addresses: from <EMAIL IT WAS SENT FROM BY THE SYSTEM> [2948/119] 
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Welcome to <i>, HTML HERE </p>
</body>
```

I have been unable to replicate it, have no idea what x-pstn is and no idea how to fix this for those clients.

Can anyone shed some light? (I'm willing to share my Zend Mail code if it helps, but I think this might be something else).

Comment: Sounds vaguely like Postini?  Google hits seem to corroborate.  http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/header_levels.html

Comment: A copy of the original headers from the outgoing message might be helpful.  I'm speculating that you have something funny after the MIME headers, like an empty line or an oddly encoded header field.